# Newly imported OVR prefabs of DK2

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

Upon upgrading to DK2 by removing the old OVR stuff and importing the new ones, the 2 OVR prefabs still complain that:

*The associated script cannot be loaded.*

As seen in the attached images, the scripts are attached to the prefabs and ticked.

How do I re-attach something that seems to be attached already?

Or is there a different meaning to this error message?

These 2 prefabs are the newly-imported DK2 prefabs. I did remove everything to do with DK1 and anything with 'Oculus' and 'OVR' in its name, but these 2 are the ones that already come with DK2's SDK (i.e. the new scripts are there) so I wonder why this happens, and how I can resolve it?

Thanks

[image: 1st screenshot]

[image: 2nd screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, is there any log which contains the information about problem?
if yes please add log information.

Secondly, Oculus DK2 sdk change it's content so often. When it's changed  i delete it's all prefabs from scene and contents from Unity. Then add new SDK and prefabs to my scene. Last Oculus SDK has 3 Camera. Left-Center-Right. So i think you need to add last sdk prefabs your scene again. If problem does not solves,
Create new project and add last SDK, if there is no prefab which contains 3 camera maybe your package has problem. Maybe firstly you check it with another fresh project before delete all contents from your main project.